# using method of moments with gumbel_r in Python scipy.stats.gumbel_r

Tags: python, scipy

I want to calculate value of a given data for 2, 5, 10, 25, 50, and 100 return years. I need to use Gumbel dist with method of moments. However, the code below is not working.

```
return_years_5min=stats.gumbel_r.ppf([0.50,0.80,0.90,0.96,0.98,0.99],  loc=mean_each_col[0], scale=std_each_col[0], moments='mv')
```

Does anyone know if this is possible, and if so how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `loc` and `scale` parameters of `gumbel_r` are not the mean and standard deviation of the distribution, so you should not use the mean and std. dev. of the data set as the `loc` and `scale` parameters.

If it is acceptable to use the maximum likelihood method instead of the method of moments, you can use the `fit()` method to estimate the parameters (`data` is assumed to be your original data set):

```
loc, scale = stats.gumbel_r.fit(data)
```

SciPy doesn't include an implementation of the method of moments for its distributions, so if you must use that method, you'll have to implement it.  The formulas for the mean and variance of the `gumbel_r` distribution are simple enough that it only requires a few lines of code to implement the method:

```
def gumbel_r_mom(x):
    """
    Method of moments estimate of the location and scale
    for the Gumbel distribution, based on the *central*
    moments (i.e. the mean and variance).
    """
    scale = np.sqrt(6)/np.pi * np.std(x)
    loc = np.mean(x) - np.euler_gamma*scale
    return loc, scale
```

Instead of using `stats.gumbel_r.fit`, you would use

```
loc, scale = gumbel_r_mom(data)
```

Then compute the return levels as

```
return_years_1HR = stats.gumbel_r.ppf([0.50,0.80,0.90,0.96,0.98,0.99], loc=loc, scale=scale)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I have to use method of moments. Do you if there is a way to do that using Scipy?

Comment: Thanks it was just what I was looking for.

Comment: Do you know how I can use the (std) and (interval) function to calculate the standard deviation and confidence interval of each calculated return period in the example above?

Comment: Do you know how I can use the (std) and (interval) function to calculate the standard deviation and confidence interval of each calculated return period in the example above?

Comment: Is the function `gumbel_r_mom` based on some scientific article that gives those formulas? how did you know those correspond to the method of moments for Gumbel?

Comment: @develarist, the formulas for the mean and variance of the  Gumbel distribution can be found in the [Gumbel distribution wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumbel_distribution).  Set those equal to the sample mean and sample variance, and solve for β and μ--it is two steps of simple algebra.  Note that I used the [*central* moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_moment) (i.e. moments about the mean), which in this case just means I used the sample variance and the formula for the distribution's variance, rather than using the raw moment (i.e. the moment about 0).

Comment: thanks, so all I have to do for any distribution is equate their analytical moment solutions to the sample moments of an empirical dataset in order to solve for parameters that I can turn around and plug into the overall pdf to generate the best fit. could you recommend a source article that conducts this procedure step-by-step in writing, in example form? any distribution would do. carrying out operations by word-of-mouth is not as secure as actually having reference material for back up